# Upper Darboux integral of $f:[0,1] \times [0,2] \to R^2, f(x,y)=x^2y$

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

How can I find the infimum of the upper Darboux sum of the function: 
$$f:[0,1] \times [0,2] \to R^2,f(x,y)=x^2y$$

Also, I would like to avoid using the formula of the sum of first n squares, if possible.